# Cesium GeoServer error : An error occurred in "WebMapServiceImageryProvider": Failed to obtain image tile

Tags: geoserver, wms, cesiumjs

I'm trying to run Cesium with GeoServer in order to learn and practice things I need to do.
I have installed and downloaded everything needed but when I am trying to run the basic examples from Cesium \ GeoServer I get the error mentioned above.

My code is the following :

```
    <script>
    var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
    var provider = new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
        layers: '',
        proxy: new Cesium.DefaultProxy('/proxy/')
    });

    viewer.imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(provider);
</script>
```

and the error is

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Cesium.js:21186 An error occurred in "WebMapServiceImageryProvider": Failed to obtain image tile X: 1 Y: 0 Level: 0.
```

when removing the proxy field, I get this error

```
Image from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:64365' is therefore not allowed access. Cesium.js:21186 An error occurred in "WebMapServiceImageryProvider": Failed to obtain image tile X: 0 Y: 0 Level: 0.
```

I have googled it and tried to configure the web.xml file according to the CORS IIS7 (running VS15) guide but with no luck.

Any chance someone know what can I do ?

Comment: It's works fro me only localy, hope you've resolved it.